# To print selective column fields into row

Tags: awk

Would like to read first line then print $1, $3, $4 as first row then $2, $3, $4 as second row and so on ...

Input.txt

```
10,20,abc,def
70,40,xxx,yyy
30,50,mno,pqr
```

Expected Output.txt

```
10,abc,def
20,abc,def
70,xxx,yyy
40,xxx,yyy
30,mno,pqr
50,mno,pqr
```

Looking for your suggestions !!

Comment: I'm not sure why you've accepted an answer that doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach using awk: simply print what you want, using a comma as Input/Output Field Separator:

```
~$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $1,$3,$4;print $2,$3,$4}' f.txt
10,abc,def
20,abc,def
70,xxx,yyy
40,xxx,yyy
30,mno,pqr
50,mno,pqr
```

With sed: find first field, second, rest; print 1st/rest - print 2nd/rest

```
~$ sed -e 's/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1,\3\n\2,\3/' f.txt
10,abc,def
20,abc,def
70,xxx,yyy
40,xxx,yyy
30,mno,pqr
50,mno,pqr
```

Answer (score 2):

In one step, giving the updated desired output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]} $2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' ref.txt input.txt
10,20,abc,def,10,red
10,20,abc,def,20,blue
```

Explanation:

```
FNR==NR  # only true when processing the first file (ref.txt)
{ 
  a[$1] = $0;   # build index for lines in ref.txt using $1 as the key
  next          # skip any further actions going to directly to next line of ref.txt
}

# (By here we know we are processing past the first file, input.txt in this case)
# If the first field exists in our index, print the line along with the corresponding line from ref.txt:
$1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}

# repeat for the second field: 
$2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)$/\1,\3,\4\n\2,\3,\4/g' file
10,abc,def
20,abc,def
70,xxx,yyy
40,xxx,yyy
30,mno,pqr
50,mno,pqr
```

Comment: Normally I applaud alternative solutions but this one just gave me a headache :-)

Comment: Using `-r`, you do not need to escape the `()`, so you get `sed -r 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)$/\1,\3,\4\n\2,\3,\4/g'`

Comment: yep, but sed in OSX won't support `-r`